# File upload control inside dialog box has no file in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to upload a file using file upload control in asp.net

control is inside dialog box. On button click event, control is empty.

below is my code. edited here please check it.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal_family" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
                            aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                                <div class="modal-content">

                                    <div class="modal-body row">

                                        <div class="col-md-12">

                                            <div id="add1">
                                                <div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
                                                    <p>
                                                        Title

                                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtTitle" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox></p>
                                                    <span class="btn btn-white btn-file"><span class="fileupload-new"><i class="fa fa-paper-clip">
                                                    </i>Select file</span>

                                                        <asp:FileUpload ID="upldfile" runat="server" onchange="UploadFile(this)" ClientIDMode="Static" />
                                                    </span>

                                                        <p> <br />
                                                        <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="false"  data-dismiss="modal" OnClick="Upload" Style="display: none" class="btn btn-danger" /></p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

javascript here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function UploadFile(fileUpload) {
    alert(fileUpload);
    if (fileUpload.value != '') {

        document.getElementById("<%=btnSave.ClientID%>").click();
    }
}
```

code behind:

```
 public void Upload(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("sfzsfg");

        if (upldfile.HasFile) // upldfile is null here 
        {

        }
}
```

Comment: whole part is inside update panel... Is that the reason not working for me?

Comment: You wrote affirmative sentences and fully working code. In what your question?

Comment: and when i print the fileupload value in javascript it always shows wrong path. For eg: if i choose a file from D:/some folder/filename but shows as C:/fakepath/filename

Comment: you have to add __doPostBack('<%= btnSave.ClientID%>', '');

Comment: The `FileUpload` Control needs a full PostBack. So it won't work with an `UpdatePanel`. Place the upload outside the panel or assign a full postback to `btnSave`.

Comment: Hi Kevin, no its not working for me

Comment: then try with adding tag <Triggers><asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSave" /></Triggers> in your update panel after </ContentTemplate>

Comment: Already added Post back Trigger

Comment: Removed update panel and checked my code. Still returns fileupload.hasfile is false

Answer (score 1):

your code is proper I have just put trigger and it working

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div id="add1">
                        <div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
                            <p>
                                Title

       <asp:TextBox ID="txtTitle" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                            </p>
                            <span class="btn btn-white btn-file"><span class="fileupload-new"><i class="fa fa-paper-clip"></i>Select file</span>

                                <asp:FileUpload ID="upldfile" runat="server" onchange="UploadFile(this)" />
                            </span>
                            <p>
                                <br />
                                <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="false" data-dismiss="modal" OnClick="Upload" Style="display: none" class="btn btn-danger" />
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
              <%--  <Triggers>
                    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSave" />
                </Triggers>--%>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

rest thing is same as you have posted

Please try.

Comment: I already added as you did but issue not resolved. beacuse problem is file upload is inside dialog box(popup). found cause but dont know how to fix it

Comment: can you please remove UseSubmitBehavior from button and check

Comment: If i remove UseSubmitBehavior  , button click is not triggering.  document.getElementById("<%=btnSave.ClientID%>").click(); this one not working

Comment: Can anyone help me. I dont have much knowledge in handling jquery dialog box

Comment: can you check that when your button click event fires at that time does that dialog is exists in DOM or not.